# Sql query to get Unique Field combinations

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to get the below results from a Single Table which contains Codes.

```
From :
CodesMaster Table
-----------
Code
-----
1
2
3
4

To : 
Code1 Code2
----- -----
2   1
3   1
4   1
3   2
4   2
4   3
```

This Query returns all combinations.

```
select C1.Code, C2.Code from 
    CodesMaster C1, CodesMaster C2 
    where C1.Code <> C2.Code
```

But I need to filter the unique combinations.
Eg : if 1 - 2 exists then I don't need 2 - 1

EDIT : IDS are not always Integers. In real it will be like : ADE1, BDE3

Comment: Which is it? MySql, or Sql Server? Those are two very different DB engines.

Answer (score 4):

```
select C1.Code, C2.Code 
from CodesMaster C1
inner join CodesMaster C2 ON C1.Code > C2.Code
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention, I have given the IDs as integer to illustrate the question. Ideally it will have Alpha Character Eg : ADE1, BDE3

Answer (score 2):

```
select C1.Code, C2.Code from 
CodesMaster C1, CodesMaster C2 
where C1.Code < C2.Code
```

Comment: Sorry I missed to mention, I have given the IDs as integer to illustrate the question. Ideally it will have Alpha Character Eg : ADE1, BDE3

Comment: Strings are comparable also.